# How to get values from a list

Tags: python, list

I've seen a few questions about copying parts from Arrays or list, but I still don't understand the logic behind it... It makes no sense for me that I can get each values by calling them by index, but it is not possible to get a part of the list by calling it by index, too...

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>>x[2]
2
>>>x[4]
4
>>>x[2:4]
[2,3]
```

What I am expecting in the last line would be that the command returns the value with index two,three and four !

```
>>> x[2:4]
[2,3,4]
```

Is there a command that does it the way I thought it would be?

Comment: You need to read on how the slice operator works. What you are trying to do is subscript the list. Start by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation here, this might help you

Comment: How about `x[2:4+1]` ?

Comment: @DavidG Yea I linked that. OP can also read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: @jadsq The more appropriate logic is `x[start:until]`, or `x[start:end-1]`, where the RHS of the slice operator is not inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing that `x[2:4]` gets all values where the index is `2 <= index < 4`. Therefore, you get index `2` and `3`, but not `4`. This is done so that you can always tell the size of a partial list (not just in python but in computing in general) by subtracting the upper bound by the lower bound. 4 - 2 = 2, therefore the list has two items in it.

There is an interesting piece of writing by E.W. Dijkstra about this if you care to read it [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

Answer (score 0):

The operation that you are performing :

```
x[2:4]
```

is called the `slicing operation`. The format of it such that, for a `list[x:y]` you get the values in index from the range `x` to `y-1`. ie, `list[x]...list[y-1]`

Hence, when you do x[2:4] , you will get the values from

```
x[2]...x[4-1] => x[2]...x[3]
```

Hence you have for :

```
>>> x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x[2:4]
=> [2, 3]

#should be
>>> x[2:5]
=> [2, 3, 4]
```

A few reading references :

- [How to Slice Lists/Arrays and Tuples in Python](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)
- [Understanding
  Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

`x[2:5]`

Because writing `x[a:b]`starts from index `a` up to and not including index `b`
So in your case you needed `x[a:b+1]`